# AWS CloudWatch Events trigger SNS on STS role assuming for cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a cross-account architecture and I'm setting up a CloudWatch event for the STS role assuming into another account. I have CloudTrail enabled on the account, the logs from CloudTrail are stored in a separate accounts s3 bucket. The SNS feeds into SES to send an email upon assumption.

For some reason, this event pattern won't trigger when the role is assumed! Any ideas?

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.sts"
  ],
   "detail-type": [
     "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
   ],
   "detail": {
     "eventSource": ["sts.amazonaws.com"],
     "eventName": ["AssumeRole"],
     "requestParameters": {
       "roleArn": ["arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/RoleName"]
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this in the future..

IAM lives in the N. Virginia region! Make sure to audit the logs there for STS

Comment: Also, if you have enabled regional STS endpoints, you need to create a rule in each region.

Comment: Did this worked for you? I'm having simillar issue and although it is in N.Virginia it doesn't work for me .